# Sound played after small delay in Android App

Tags: android, eclipse

I have many buttons in my app and many short song to play like piano etc.

But using below code, when app plays a song, there is a **delay of about a half second**, between button click and App playing a Sound.

How can I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        final Button g1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu1);
        final Button g2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu2);
        final Button g3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu3);
        final Button g4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu4);
        final Button g5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu5);






                g1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.closehh);
                    @Override
                     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) 
                    { 
                        int action = motionevent.getAction(); 
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                        {         
                                   mp.start();
                                   mp.seekTo(0);
                                   g1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0005z);

                        }
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            g1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0005);

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                g2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.openhh);
                    @Override
                     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) 
                    { 
                        int action = motionevent.getAction(); 
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                        {         
                                   mp.start();
                                   mp.seekTo(0);
                                   g2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0005z);

                        }
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            g2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0005);

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class is for low-latency playback of sound resources. It uses the MediaPlayer but loads streams into memory for more responsive playback